# Compare 2 JSONs - The property count - c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Assume the recurring code is generating huge JSON based on some nested structure. Suppose there comes a bad data on one bad day, and our new JSON is 30% smaller in size from last good JSON.

My goal is to count all the main properties while deserializing the JSON and compare it from past count statistics and notify the JSON producer that new JSON is bad.

Is there a simple way to do this? Using C# and NewtonSoft.Json for deserialization.

For ex: Suppose JSON encapsulates n-array tree like structure. Each node contains the `source` field as string (which can be null). Now, in first run 100 nodes were present in JSON and 70% of them contain valid `source` string. In second run there were 105 nodes with 80% of valid `source` string (GOOD data). In third run there were 40 nodes with 20% of valid `source` string. I consider this as "bad" data. I want to fail here without ingesting newer bad data.

Each time we run recurring code, I want to compare it against the last run's count statistics, and want to fail the code if the data is bad as described in example.

Comment: Can you give an example how a "bad" JSON looks like compared to a "good" one?

Comment: Why close the question - seems like a real world problem while refreshing the data.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is business logic and nothing the serializer should care about.

I think the best way to this is to add a validation step between deserialization and processing of the deserialized data.

This means that the validator iterates over the deserialized POCO classes and counts how many nodes have a valid `source` string. In case they are below a certain threshold then execution should halt and the JSON producer should be notified.

If you want the threshold to be dynamic (i.e. it should depend on the previous count) then you have to store the counted value in a file or database to retrieve it when the next JSON arrives.